# VB Web Service call error Object reference not set

Tags: vb.net, web-services, rest

Hey all I am trying to figure out why I am getting the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on line 2 of code:

```
1.  Dim HTPCws As HTPCWS.ServiceVB
2.  Dim returned As String = HTPCws.DisplayMessageVB(what2send)
```

When I know **what2send** does have a value to send....

The Web Service code is this:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function DisplayMessageVB(ByVal beingSent As String) As String
    _strfromws = beingSent
    Return "DONE"
End Function
```

What could I be forgetting?

Comment: Is HTPCWS (with CAPS) on your References?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTPCws` has not been instantiated. Change the code to:

```
Dim HTPCws = New HTPCWS.ServiceVB()
Dim returned As String = HTPCws.DisplayMessageVB(what2send)
```

`Dim HTPCws As HTPCWS.ServiceVB` declares a variable but does not assign it an object. Also the naming is a bit confusing. Better:

```
Dim service = New HTPCWS.ServiceVB()
Dim returned As String = service.DisplayMessageVB(what2send)
```